# httpd -t not working on Ubuntu for Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd

When I navigate to /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.11/bin which is my Apache install directory and I try to do something like this:

```
httpd -t
```

I get this kind of an error:

```
No command 'httpd' found, did you mean:
 Command 'dhttpd' from package 'dhttpd' (universe)
 Command 'xttpd' from package 'xtide' (universe)
 Command 'thttpd' from package 'thttpd' (universe)
```

Any idea why that would happen?  The suggestions of the 3 commands do not work either :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the command

```
apache2ctl
```

If there is a httpd bin file in that directory then you need to put a . in front of the command

```
./httpd -t
```

Comment: What was that supposed to do?  It gave me some help with the proper usage of that command.

Comment: In debian based systems the apache is typical called apaceh2 and not httpd. As far as I know the apache2ctl command is the same as the httpd command on redhat based systems. So you can do apache2ctl -t to perform a syntax test which is what httpd -t does I believe.

You can also control apache (start,stop) with apache2 ctl as well.

Comment: Now I have this error :) No command 'spache2ctl' found, did you mean: Command 'apache2ctl' from package 'apache2.2-common' (main)

Comment: typo in the command, apache2ctl not spache2ctl